# how to filter json object data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Input of Json Object:

```
{"data":[
    {"itemID":100,"Testcase1":"aaa","status":"Active"},
    {"itemID":100,"Testcase1":"bbb","status":"No"},
    {"itemID":100,"Testcase1":"ccc","status":"Active"},
    {"itemID":101,"Testcase1":"zzz","status":"Active"}
]}
```

Expected Output of Json Object:

```
[{
    "itemID":"100",
    "Testcase1":"aaa", 
    "Testcase1":"bbb", 
    "Testcase1":"ccc", 
    "status":"Active",
    "status":"No",
    "status":"Active"
},
{
    "itemID":"101",
    "Testcase1":"zzz",
    "status":"Active"
}]
```

anybody help me?

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do

Comment: what kind of filter?

Comment: yes i want to restructure the object like expected output

Comment: It's just extracting objects from data object.

Comment: @George by the looks of it, he wants to merge the ones with the same `itemID`

Comment: That object is invalid. You can't have the same property multiple times on object. So having `"Testcase1":"aaa", "Testcase1":"bbb",  "Testcase1":"ccc"` wouldn't work. Not to mention it wouldn't be useful.

Comment: yes duplicate key is not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be this helps you. This is not the correct way. Because duplicate key is not allowed in object. whatever as it your request. I have create a string of your required format.

please checkit [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c573jutp/)

```
var dataVal={"data":[
     {"itemID":100,"Testcase1":"aaa","status":"Active"},
     {"itemID":100,"Testcase1":"bbb","status":"No"},
     {"itemID":100,"Testcase1":"ccc","status":"Active"},
     {"itemID":101,"Testcase1":"zzz","status":"Active"}
]};

var arrayVal = dataVal.data;
var DistinctID=[];
var resultStr="";
for (var elements in arrayVal){

     if($.inArray(arrayVal[elements].itemID, DistinctID) == -1){
      DistinctID.push(arrayVal[elements].itemID)
     }
}

for (var items in DistinctID){
    resultStr +='{"itemID":"'+DistinctID[items]+'",';
    for (var elements in arrayVal){
        if(arrayVal[elements].itemID==DistinctID[items]){
            resultStr +='"Testcase1":"'+arrayVal[elements].Testcase1+'",';
            resultStr +='"status":"'+arrayVal[elements].status+'",';
        }
    }

resultStr = resultStr.substring(0, resultStr.length - 1);

    resultStr= resultStr+'},';

}
resultStr = resultStr.substring(0, resultStr.length - 1);
resultStr='['+resultStr+']';
alert((resultStr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "JSON Object" is a string, you can call `JSON.parse()` on it:

```
var data = '{"data":[{ ... }]}';

var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
```

This will give you data in the following structure:

[image: Example]

---

Your *expected output* isn't a valid object. Object keys must be unique. An object cannot have three `Testcase1` keys or three `status` keys.

Comment: I guess he wants to extracts objects array from data object (not sure about it).

Comment: @enguerranws he wants to make a single object out of the 3 ones with the same itemID

Comment: @Spokey I just understood that :)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to **extract objects from data object** ?

Ok then, a pure JS solution :

```
var obj = {"data":[{"itemID":100,"Testcase1":"aaa","status":"Active"},

{"itemID":100,"Testcase1":"bbb","status":"No"},{"itemID":100,"Testcase1":"ccc","status":"Active"},

{"itemID":101,"Testcase1":"zzz","status":"Active"}]};

var newArray = [];

for( var i = 0; i < obj['data'].length; i++) {
   newArray.push(obj['data'][i]);
}
```

And a live demo of that : http://jsfiddle.net/seLwmbyp/1/ (see the console for the result) > `[Object, Object, Object, Object]`

Comment: In this way  display the duplicate values

Comment: If you don't want duplicate values, you should say it in your question ?